# How to use hosts Windows service in a Windows Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have a Windows service which runs as web app server with name `MyWebServer0` which has path to executable as `D:\Config\MyWebApplicationServer.exe` and it uses several dlls which are inside `Config` folder.

Now, when I run the container is it possible that it knows about this host's service and use it to process http requests?

I tried to run the container with `--network host` but it seems that it doesn't work with Windows containers.